# Trying to scrape a Lazada product page

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi I'm try to scrape a product in lazada.com.ph but when I try to load the link it gives me and error that looks like this

> We have detected unusual traffic from your network, please try again later.

I can't start my code writing as this impedes me

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getData(url):
session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get(url)
response.html.render(sleep=1)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, 'lxml')

print(soup.text)

lazada = 'https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/poco-x3-pro-8gb-ram-256gb-rom-android-smartphone-i1897541032-s8049001075.html?spm=a2o4l.home.flashSale.2.568f359dVjXEgp&search=1&mp=1&c=fs&clickTrackInfo=%7B%22rs%22%3A%220.07556916303173189%22%2C%22prior_score%22%3A%220%22%2C%22submission_discount%22%3A%2213%25%22%2C%22iss%22%3A%220.07556916303173189%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22entrance%22%2C%22prior_type%22%3A%22racing%22%2C%22userid%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sca%22%3A%22129%22%2C%22hourtonow%22%3A%2215%22%2C%22abid%22%3A%22178638%22%2C%22itemid%22%3A%221897541032_0_racing_0.07556916303173189_0.07556916303173189%22%2C%22pvid%22%3A%22fb0dc67d-d4da-4a00-8875-f372cd6be63a%22%2C%22pos%22%3A%220%22%2C%22rms%22%3A%220.0%22%2C%22c2i%22%3A%220.0%22%2C%22scm%22%3A%221007.17760.178638.%22%2C%22ss%22%3A%220.07556916303173189%22%2C%22i2i%22%3A%220.0%22%2C%22ms%22%3A%220.07556916303173189%22%2C%22itr%22%3A%220.13743589743589743%22%2C%22mt%22%3A%22racing%22%2C%22its%22%3A%221950%22%2C%22promotion_price%22%3A%2213990.00%22%2C%22anonid%22%3A%22dacd613a-5ef7-417e-81af-9cbca55c0971%22%2C%22FinalScore%22%3A%220.053083501756191254%22%2C%22isc%22%3A%22268%22%2C%22iss2%22%3A%220.5778039211824528%22%2C%22data_type%22%3A%22flashsale%22%2C%22iss1%22%3A%220.016712397106510353%22%2C%22config%22%3A%22%22%2C%22HP_score%22%3A%220.053083501756191254%22%2C%22channel_id%22%3A%220000%22%7D&scm=1007.17760.178638.0'
getData(lazada)
```

As you can see it's just a simple parse and print
I'm using the library requests-html to simplify the headers.
At some post that I read it's saying about the script but I don't know where to look beyond here as I'm fairly new to this. It's like its blocking me to scrape the site.

Comment: "It's like its blocking me to scrape the site." - Thats exactly what its doing

Comment: yeah but trying to change the header is not working. do you have a suggestion on this type of problem?

Answer (score 0):

Lazada has taken measures to (in you case successfully) prevent people from scraping it.

Your goal is not to make a simple request to that website,
but to mimic a browser as good as you can.

As you are new to the topic, try to scrape an easier target first, like your local newspaper or something.

Furthermore, there's always the chance someone on the internet has already done it. And your in luck, a simple search would have brought this gem to you :)

https://kenciceron45.wixsite.com/krontek/post/can-we-scrape-it-eps-3-lazada